# Provisioning profile is about to expire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have issued an app which is not in app store is about to expire its provisioning profile and I have updated the provisioninng profile on the Apple Developer Website, will it automatically update the provisioning profile on the issued app or do I need to rebuild the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer. No, you don't need to rebuild the app.

Refer : https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/

Comment: Thanks alot! this gave me a relief! because i need to rebuild around 200 ipa again if ever.